# Elementary Os Secure Boot Failure after install

Tags: system-installation

I tried install Elementary Os 5.1.6 Hera but after enroll the mok key and reboot... The system says Verification Failure and only disabling secure boot i can boot... Is there any way to install it keeping secure boot working?

Comment: Yes. Create separate EFI partition for Elementary during installation of the OS. Format as FAT32 and mount as /boot

Comment: Will try... Thanks for the answer... I created a separate boot partition but on ext4... will try with that